# How to access a JSON file in my controller

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app, I have a JSON file filled with data in my public directory (I.E. `public/data/articles.json`.

I have an article route where I would like to load in this data and display it in the front-end. How could I do this successfully? I am willing to use the model hook, however I don't know of a solution off-hand.

I currently have the following code in my controller. However, this doesn't work (most likely because the data is loaded in after it is rendered).

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default Controller.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    $.getJSON("/data/articles.json", function (data) {
      console.log("test");
      console.log(data);
      this.articleData = data;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can literally just write `return $.getJSON("/data/articles.json");` in your routes `model` hook and then access the data as `model` in your template/controller.

A bit more elegant would be to use `fetch`:

```
async model() {
  const res = await fetch('/data/articles.json');
  return res.json();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this answer a lot because I can use a model hook. Any reason why you added the `async` before the model?

Comment: yes, its an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) so you can use `await`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you accessing that file somewhere else? I would recommend putting the file inside your `app` folder and importing it. It could be inside `app/utils/sample-articles.js` or another folder for "static data". That way you don't have to do that extra request.

```js
// app/utils/sample-articles.js
export default {
  // Articles
};
```

Then in your controller you can just `import` it like:

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import sampleArticles from 'your-app/utils/sample-articles';

export default Controller.extend({
  articleData: sampleArticles
});
```

Also in your example, you're assigning the value of `data` to a variable in an inner scope. You would need to refactor that like:

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { set } from '@ember/object';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default Controller.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    $.getJSON("/data/articles.json", (data) => {
      console.log("test");
      console.log(data);
      set(this, "articleData", data); // Use `set`
  }
});
```